# Fragment Lollipop Transitions

Tags: android, android-fragments, transactions, fragment

I have set up fragment transitions on entering and exiting the fragment.  And when ever I press back android throws this error:

NullPointerException:  Attempt to invoke virtual method getAllowReturnTransitionOverlap() on a null object reference.

This is my code to add slide transitions to fragments.  Anyone know why I'm getting this error?  I have an activity that holds a fragment.  I replace fragments and add them to the backstack.  I have a few activities which hold all the fragments in the application.

```
if ( AndroidUtils.isMinimumSdkLevel( android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP ) )
    {
      if ( enter == null )
      {
        enter = new Slide();
        enter.setDuration( 400 );
        enter.setInterpolator( new DecelerateInterpolator() );
      }

      if ( exit == null )
      {
        exit = new Slide();
        exit.setDuration( 400 );
        exit.setInterpolator( new DecelerateInterpolator() );
      }

      fragment.setEnterTransition( enter );
      fragment.setReturnTransition( exit );
    }
```

Comment: do you mean going back to another activity or just exiting the fragment in the same activity ?

Comment: Either, as long as the fragment is popped off the backstack

Comment: Working on this myself. @George, did you ever find a solution? If I find something I'll be sure to post an answer.